# Hatdash.com still has legal disclaimer from skyrimvsmw3.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, winterbash

It's a rather minor bug, but there's still no reason for it to be there.

[image: legal stuffz]

Comment: Can't repro here. Chrome 17 ;)

Comment: maybe we just *really* wanted to cover our bases and not get sued...

Comment: @DavidFullerton: That's not a bad idea with Bethesda's lawyers.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed on Chrome 16.

Alternatively, couldn't the other games mentioned be added to the disclaimer instead?

Comment: Yeah, but it's pretty minor usage now, and some change needs made either way. (btw, did you think that it'd be different on Chrome? :P )

Comment: @Ullallulloo — As a web developer, I'd rather have the browser & version when it doesn't matter than not have them when it does!  ;-)

Comment: @Ullallulloo I may or may not have posted this just for the hat.